# Extract-Transform-Load from Oracle to SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-server-2005, parallel-processing, etl

I've been hanging around SO for a couple of days found the community great! I'm certain that someone can give me an opinion on my question:

We have raw data in an Oracle server and our query fetches around 312 MB of data (just the columns we need joined across a couple of tables). This is done using `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`, the `FetchSize = RowSize * 512`, which is around 3.9 MB. I'm currently using `OracleDataReader` and do the processing in his `while()` loop.

The results of the processing are then written using prepared parameterized `IF EXISTS() UPDATE ELSE INSERT`. From this DB we can return our needed data directly in Excel after joining the dimension tables.

I'm looking at ways to improve the performance. Is it possible to multi-thread `BULK INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s and also multi-thread the processing of rows (say start 4 Threads and divide incomming rows evenly between them) and does something like `BULK UPDATE` exist in SQL Server 2005?

I'm **not** looking for copy-paste code, I'm more interested in already existing best-practices or patterns.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what dividing incoming rows between threads would gain you, given that they all have to be inserted in the same target table.  Inserting in the database will likely be the bottleneck, and multiple threads on the client probably just end up waiting for each other.

My normal approach for this would be to use SqlBulkCopy to read the rows from the OracleDataReader and insert them into an empty staging table in the target database.

Then process the staging table in batches, UPSERTing into the target table.  Each batch would be a transaction.

Comment: I'm assuming `OracleDataReader` implements `IDataReader` then, but would this mean I have to do all data transformations in SQL? Or can I somehow overload `OracleDataReader` so it returns the columns already calculated? +1 for telling me about `SqlBulkCopy` and `MERGE`!

Comment: Yes, this would imply that you need to do the transforms in the SQL - e.g. in the Oracle query.  If you can't do that, an alternative might be to write your own wrapper class around OracleDataReader that implements IDataReader and does the transforms you want.

Comment: So, inserting in the DB really was the bottleneck. Thanks for your great suggestions, I'm accepting the answer!